type narrowing doesn't work when using a non-type-literal field as a tag
Inside the test function, b type does not narrow to string when a type is string.
Why? I don't understand why it behaves this way.
type Foo = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
};
type Bar = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
};

type Uinon = Foo | Bar;

function test({ a, b }: Uinon) {
  if (typeof a === "string") {
    a;
    b;
  }
}

playground
If a is type literal as shown below, this is fine, but if it is not type literal, why is it not type narrowing?
type Foo = {
  a: "A";
  b: string;
};
type Bar = {
  a: "B";
  b: number;
};


The feature you are using is a special case of type narrowing, called a discriminated union. From the TypeScript Handbook v1:

Discriminating Unions
A common technique for working with unions is to have a single field which uses literal types which you can use to let TypeScript narrow down the possible current type.

And this discrimination is only implemented for literal types. The new handbook doesn't state it so explicitly as a rule, but also only uses literal types.
You can still implement your own type predicate to narrow down your Union:
function isFoo(u: Union): u is Foo {
  return typeof u.a === "string"
}

function test(u: Union) {
  if (isFoo(u)) {
    u.a;
    u.b;
  }
}


"outdated" is a strong word. There is the TS handbook version 1 (which you linked) and later the team released the TS handbook version 2 which restructured some topics and added more things that weren't in the old version. "Outdated" makes it sound like it's wrong but virtually all topics covered in v1 are still relevant and correct. In fact, few things can't even be found in v2.

Well the banner at the top says quite clearly "This page has been deprecated". I can replace it with v1 :)

@RobinDeSchepper "deprecated" does not necessarily mean the same "outdated". A "outdated" documentation has a quite strong (admittedly informal) conotation of being "wrong", while "deprecated" has a quite clear definition of still being valid but subject to removal in the (possibly near) future ... How far in the future depends on the product. Android for instance still supports features (like Camera API v1) which have been deprected years ago ...

@RobinDeSchepper
Of course, i can do a type predicate to narrow down the union, but my question is not how to narrow down the type, but why it only works with literal type, because I didn't find anything that says it only works on literal types like you said.  Is it a logical issue or a functional issue, or should I just understand it as a feature that requires the literal type to be used as a tag?

Yes, as the official documentation there states, discriminated type unions are a feature that only work with literals as the tag. You'd have to ask a TypeScript developer why that is. My best guess is that it's a tradeoff against complexity. I can't find any official spec or source code to confirm this.

@RobinDeSchepper i got it. thank you for the answer!
